I am trying to install freeglut3 but when I try to do so, it give an error
I entered sudo apt-get install freeglut3
But it gives:
"Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree... Done
Reading state information... Done
E: Unable to locate package freeglut3
"

What is your Ubuntu version? Have you enabled the universe repository?

It's Ubuntu 23.10'

First, enable the universe repository with sudo add-apt-repository universe.
Then install freeglut3 with sudo apt install freeglut3
If you are running Ubuntu 23.10, then the package freeglut3 is not available. Install freeglut3-dev instead.

sudo apt update is not neccessary after add-apt-repository unless you use the -n  or --no-update option.
